# Why is there a Uncaught ReferenceError in my code even though I already referenced newTODO in my js file?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const itemCount = 0
const uncheckedCount = 0

//Update counter
function upDateCounter() {
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = itemCount
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = uncheckedCount

// New ToDO
function newTODO(){
  var task = prompt("Enter ToDo", "New ToDo")
  if (task.lenght >0){
    itemCount +=1
    uncheckedCount =+1
    upDateCounter()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTODO()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error shows up when I run it in chrome Despite having a function newTODO in the JS file and referencing in the HTML there is still a error when I press the button Help!

Comment: You don't seem to close any of your `{` in your JavaScript. Your `upDateCounter` and `newTODO` both have a `{` but no matching `}`, and the same for your if-statement.

Comment: You do have another error though. You try to modify a variable declared with [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Answer (score 1):

Here:

- Unmatching braces
- You are modifying a `const`
- `lenght` should be `length`

```
var itemCount = 0
var uncheckedCount = 0

//Update counter
function upDateCounter() {
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = itemCount
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = uncheckedCount
}

// New ToDO
function newTODO(){
  var task = prompt("Enter ToDo", "New ToDo")
  if (task.length >0){
    itemCount +=1
    uncheckedCount =+1
    upDateCounter()
  }
}
```